# What are the application for CCA

Tags: multivariate-analysis, canonical-correlation

What are the usage to find the maximal correlation between two multi variate data set X and Y?

Especially, could I use this for prediction, say, X are the features, and Y are the things that I want to predict? Based on training data, could CCA help us to do some predictions?

If not, why do we need to study CCA?